# Using OpenSSL to decrypt a .ts file

Tags: openssl, http-live-streaming, ffprobe, transport-stream

Everything is in the same directory.

**M3u8 File**:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI=MyKeyFile.key
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000000.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000001.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000002.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000003.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000004.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000005.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000006.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000007.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000008.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000009.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000010.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000011.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000012.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000013.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000014.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000015.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000016.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000017.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000018.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000019.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000020.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000021.ts
#EXTINF:10,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000022.ts
#EXTINF:3,
aes_ts_files/filesequence0000023.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

**MyKeyFile.Key**

```
tßâ0Äb‘˜p.ô[{m‚
```

I know the content is legit because if I right click on the .m3u8 and select "Play with VLC media player" it works. I need to decrypt the ts files so I can use ffprobe and inspect the content.

**Here is the OpenSSL command I've tried**:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -kfile MyKeyFile.key -iv 0 -nosalt -in aes_ts_files/filesequence0000000.ts -out aes_ts_files/filesequence0000000_out.ts
```

**Error Message**: 
bad decrypt
18676:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:c
rypto\evp\evp_enc.c:529:

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I agree and thank you for correcting me. I'll be more aware of questions I ask going forward.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-kfile` is used to derive the key from a password stored in the first line of the file.

You *already* have the actual key so you need to pass it using `-K key` where *key* is the key in hex (`xxd -p MyKeyFile.key`).

The IV is also a hex string and it's equal to the media sequence if not specified.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm still running into problems. I apologize in advance for my confusion.

Comment: C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl aes-128-cbc -d -p MyKeyFile.key -iv 0 -nosalt -in a
es_ts_files/filesequence0000000.ts -out aes_ts_files/filesequence0000000_out.ts
<br />
enter aes-128-cbc decryption password:

Comment: @user3541092 `openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in encrypted_segment.ts -out decrypted_segment.ts -nosalt -iv <iv_hex> -K <key_hex>`  where `iv` and `K` are in hex (random example `-K 0ffa87119864cffd5f63f89106f1c1c2`)

Comment: @aergistal I have a `.key` file, how would I get the respective hex string for it?

Comment: @Script47 It's in the answer: `xxd -p MyKeyFile.key`