# Get IV from AES-128 Key in PHP

Tags: php, openssl, m3u8

I have a stream in M3U8 with AES-128 encryption. I have access to the key but the IV is missing. VLC is playling the stream correctly but I have a software (ProgTV) who can't do that if the IV is not given.
How can I get the IV from the AES-128 key ? I know it is possible but I didn't understand what everyone said.
Thanks

Here is the M3U8 :

```html
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:9
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:733889
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="25419608.key"
#EXTINF:8.0000,
video1.ts
#EXTINF:8.0000,
video2.ts
#EXTINF:8.0000,
video3.ts
```

....

Comment: It not possible to get the IV from the key. There must be a default or known IV if VLC can play it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried 1 or 0 but it didn't work. I search a lot but I can't find the way to do it. Any idea ?

Comment: I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366617/using-openssl-to-decrypt-a-ts-file that the IV is also a hex string and it's equal to the media sequence. But I tried it too and it didn't work again or I miss something ?